# Running the same shell script in multiple directories at once on Unix

Tags: shell, unix, command, csh

I have 35 distinct directories, named case1 to case35 respectively. I have the same shell script in each of them and I was wondering if there is a way to execute it in every directory at once.

Comment: I am using csh rather than bash

Comment: You want to execute 35 scripts in different directories or you want to execute 1 script that runs on 35 directories?

Comment: I want to execute the same script 35 times. So I want to execute it once in every directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `csh`:

```
foreach d (case*)
  $d/script &
end
```

Or you can use `sh`/`bash` which gives a better programatic interface:

`for d in case*; do $d/script & done`

Add a `cd` before running the script if you want to be in the directory when executing the script.